# What to return after Ajax call asp.net

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

After ajax call is completed and the model is posted successfully to the controller, what should the controller return?

In my case, I just want to add an item to the wishlist and that's it, no redirect.

Comment: Could you please share your `Controller code` details and full `View Razor code`  so that it can be checked easily and then can be suggest or provide example quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Controller can return a message or somethingelse for sure that your action did successful

Answer (score 0):

This question you need to know two points, 1.What type can asp.net core return? 2.What type can ajax can receive.

**First**, Asp.net core can return the following types: `Specific type`, `IActionResult`, `ActionResult<T>`, Learn more details in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-6.0#actionresultt-type).

**Second**, Ajax can send and receive information in various formats, including `JSON`, `XML`, `HTML,` and `text files`.

From your question, I think you want to recive the model from controller and add it to the wishlist in the view. So, In my opinion, You can directly return the specified model, Asp.net core will serialize models to Json Automatically. Then you can use it in your ajax success method.

**simple demo:**

```
<div class="text-center" id="Test">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<button onclick="GetDetails(2)">submit</button>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function GetDetails(id){
             var postData = {
                    'ProductId': id,    
                };
            $.ajax({          
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Home/privacy",
                data: postData,              
                success: function (res) { 
                    document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML = res["name"];
                }
     });
                
    }
</script>
}
```

**Controller**

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student()
                {
                    Id="1",
                    Name="Jack",
                    Country="USA"
                },
                new Student()
                {
                    Id="2",
                    Name="Nacy",
                    Country="Uk"
                },
                new Student()
                {
                    Id="3",
                    Name="Lily",
                    Country="Cn"
                }
            };

[HttpPost]
        public Student Privacy(string ProductId)
        {
            var result = students.Where(x => x.Id == ProductId).FirstOrDefault();
            return result;
        }
```